# Why does including this particular INNER JOIN alias cause the query to break on SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I swear I've gone blind.  And I apologize if this is wasting anyone's time, but can someone help me troubleshoot this?  With the two lines that are commented below, it works; however, uncommenting them does not throw an error, but it returns nothing

```
 SELECT
     [USER_ID]
     ,[dbo].[E_CUSTOMERS].[START_DATE]
     ,[dbo].[E_CUSTOMERS].[STOP_DATE]
     ,[FLEX02]
     ,[FLEX03]
     ,[dbo].[E_PES_LK].[MEANING] as [pesMEANING]
     --,[dbo].[E_ACCESS_LK].[MEANING] as [accMEANING]
FROM 
    [dbo].[E_CUSTOMERS]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[E_PES_LK] on [dbo].[E_CUSTOMERS].[PESKEY_FK] = [dbo].[E_PES_LK].[PESKEY]
--INNER JOIN
--  [dbo].[E_ACCESS_LK] on [dbo].[E_CUSTOMERS].[ACCESSKEY_FK] = [dbo].[E_ACCESS_LK].[ACCESSKEY]
WHERE 
    [USER_ID] = 'TESTACCT'
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: the most obvious answer would be that there are no rows that match the join condition: `[dbo].[E_CUSTOMERS].[ACCESSKEY_FK] = [dbo].[E_ACCESS_LK].[ACCESSKEY]`

Comment: @vkp "uncommenting them does not throw an error, but it returns nothing"

Comment: I'm a weenie. thanks, everyone, for helping me see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with Lamak here;

Try this

```
 SELECT
    E.[USER_ID]
    E.[ACCESSKEY_FK]
 FROM 
    [dbo].[E_CUSTOMERS] E INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[E_PES_LK] P  on E.[PESKEY_FK] = P.[PESKEY]
 WHERE [USER_ID] = 'TESTACCT'
```

Then

```
SELECT L.[ACCESSKEY]
FROM [dbo].[E_ACCESS_LK] L
```

And make sure there is a match between both.